# Kodi package problems after upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04: libsdl2 not found

Tags: apt, upgrade, ppa, xbmc, kodi

After my HTPC system upgrade from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 I can't seem to install Kodi.

I run

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kodi kodi-bin
```

And get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kodi-bin : Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I had a few PPA's insatalled on old stystem and removed them all from sources list. I also `ppa-purge` the ream-xbmc's ppa and re added it. Some other ppa's I removed from sources list, as ppa-purgeing them failed.  The old system had XBMC running without issues. The upgrade was smooth, and had no errors.

I see some [other people](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=216169) had same problem, but solved by manually installing a deb.  This makes me think my apt is very confused, and I would rather not break my setup further.

This system was installed using an older version of [this guide](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=174854). I additionally installed Gnome for occasional web browsing.

How do I go about debugging this package problem? What would make my system not know about `libsdl2-dev`? Did I find a bug in the team-xbmc ppa?

Some more info:

```
$ apt-cache policy libsdl2-dev
libsdl2-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
     2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1 0
        500 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1 0
        500 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages

$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL*
libsdl1.2debian:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0
libsdl1.2debian:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4
libsdl-image1.2:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL_image-1.2.so.0
libsdl-image1.2:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL_image-1.2.so.0.8.4
```

Comment: The package is available for Trusty. Force the install with `sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0`

Comment: @A.B. That gives me next dependency problem `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl2-2.0-0 : Depends: libwayland-egl1-mesa (>= 10.0.2) or
                          libwayland-egl1` I actually want to fix the root cause of this package problem. Why do I have to force install anything?

Comment: ck. what version of libwayland-egl1-mesa is installed, maybe you have the lts version? `apt-cache policy libwayland-egl1-mesa*` &  ck. what mesa you are using, 14.04 orig.  or one of the lts versions.

Comment: @doug http://paste.ubuntu.com/11791594/ doesn't look like I have any `libwayland` installed.

Comment: What release/flavor are you actually running? Ubuntu or Ubuntu-Gnome would require some version of libwayland-egl1-mesa to be installed

Comment: I am running Ubuntu server 14.04, and installed Gnome afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem, as Kodi is now installing correctly:
First I found all the packages that were still hanging around from saucy by running

```
dpkg --list | grep saucy
```

One by one I removed them all using `apt-get remove <packagename>`.  (I suspect these were old packages that were installed via some weird ppa when I installed gnome.)

After removing all the saucy packages, I ran `apt-get autoremove` to cleanup the rest of the packages.  Then I ran into what seems to be a [libgl1-mesa-dri bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1279192).

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/etc/drirc', which is different from other instances of package libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
```

Luckily simple workaround of `sudo mv /etc/drirc /etc/drirc.bak2` fixed that and I could install Kodi again withouth further trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

This should clean up any broken packages.
Then you should try this again

```
sudo apt-get install kodi kodi-bin
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I ran those commands, but still get same error. It didn't look like there were any broken packages.

Comment: And why twice `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: hmm thats strange I dont know at the moment ill keep thinking on it tho @Diedrik and i didnt notice that i put 2 apt-get update sorry I'm tired.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading from 15.04 to 15.10. The solution I found here: [Ubuntu Forums: broken package libsdl2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2258315)

1. See what packages are not in the cleanly installed state (I had a lot!):

   ```bsh
   dpkg -l|sed -nr '/^.[^in]/s/^(.{78}).*/\1/p'
   ```
2. Add back the missing PPA, in my case the one from Kodi.
3. Bring every program up to the current levels and install the latest kernel:

   ```bsh
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
4. After that, Kodi could be installed again in my case; Then either continue to use the PPA or use `ppa-purge` on it.
5. In the future purge all PPAs before upgrading Ubuntu releases!